# How to add two "dropzones" on the same page, with same settings.

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I have two dropzones on the same page. One of them is hidden in popup. Need to define similar settings and default style for both of them. Can anyone help with right plugin initialization? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: MrLeeh, better help me pls.